# How save cookie JSESSIONID in browser (spring)?

Tags: spring, cookies, session-cookies

i am develop an web app and in the authentication i need to delete the cookie JSESSIONID after a user makes logout.

Imagine this situation, i have multiple servers with the same war deployed and the user A make login in the the diferent servers.

When one of connected makes logout, other all should makes logout too. Soo, i need to remove all cookies to can do it (i think this will work).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you remove the cookie, a new one will be created as soon as another JSP is hit (unless explicitly configured to not create a session).

Rather than relying on the presence of a session, use an object *in* the session to determine if a user is logged in or not.

Just invalidate the session. Don't worry about the session cookie, or you'll need to retrofit all your JSP pages that don't require a login to not create a session, and remember to do that [in perpetuity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+perpetuity).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing all of the cookies from the clients, you need to instead invalidate that cookie server-side. Basically, you are expiring their session server-side, which means that they will get a new cookie sent to them if they re-connect.

Comment: i can get all cokies when user makes logout and when i try to invalidade all cookies, doesnt work and the same user on diferent server can continue using his session.. any ideia? thanks